# how to dispose all entity created in parallel.forEach after job done?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I'm using parallel.forEach to access database with multi threads.

Let's say  we get  200,000 rows to insert, and i'm using 20 threads

Optimistically, i only need to connect DB 20 time, each thread use one connection.

i think if i write  `dbconn.dispose()`  inside the loop  it will do  200,000 connection.

But i can not write  `dbconn.dispose()`  outside for it , it will say no defined.

then how can I  write some thing like " dispose all connection  after 200,000 rows done"?

Code like:

```
myPallOpt.MaxDegreeOfParallelism=20;
parallel.forEach(source,myPallOpt,(oneRow)=>
{
     myDataEntity dbconn= new myDataEntity();
     // do data base job

     // i don't like to write  dbconn.dispose()  here 
});

//but can not  use dbconn.dispose()  here
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the overload of `Parallel.ForEach` that allows you to setup and teardown the thread. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has more details and an example.

For your scenario..

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    input, 
    () => new DbConn(), 
    (i, loopState, dbConn) => {
        // do stuff with dbConn here

        //Pass the dbConn on to the next itteration.
        return dbConn;
    },
    dbConn => dbConn.Dispose()
);
```

Comment: You forgot the return in the middle delegate, I corrected it for you.

Answer (score -1):

it's been a while.

I think Dean Ward's idea may work.

But what i did is:

1, create a thread_ID and EF connection table(list)

2, when cycle to this thread, i check if this thread is in the thread_talbe.
   if not  create a new EF connection , and save this thread ID and connection to the thread_tale.

3, when job is done,  loop close all the EF connections in the table.

code:

```
create a thread vs EF table

Parallel.ForEach(.....)=>
{
     if(thread NOT in thread table)
       {
         EF dbconn = new EF();
         tread_table.add(this_thread_ID,dbconn)
        }


      do_oneThreadJOb(data someData,EF dbconn);
});


foreah( var one in thread_table)
{
     thread_table[one].dispose();

}
```

Comment: That seems like a sub-optimal approach. Why not use what the framework already provides you?